# Making (and keeping) lines readonly in AvalonEdit

Tags: readonly, avalonedit

What is a robust way of making certain lines readonly in an AvalonEdit control? Users are allowed to change certain method bodies in a C# or VB template file but nothing else. The readonly state per line needs to be kept intact when users add or remove lines, i.e. the readonly blocks below the edited content need to shift up and down accordingly.

I'm using AvalonEdit in a WPFHost on winforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `textEditor.TextArea.ReadOnlySectionProvider` to an implementation of `IReadOnlySectionProvider`.

AvalonEdit contains the implementation `TextSegmentReadOnlySectionProvider` which allows marking segments as read-only. These read-only segments will move around when the user adds/inserts text.
`TextSegmentReadOnlySectionProvider` doesn't allow you to prevent insertions at the very beginning and end of the document (as those positions are never are within any segment), but you can inherit from the class and override `CanInsert()` to fix this special case.

Comment: I have tryied your solution and it does not work completely, while it is not allowed to insert text anymore at the offset I define, it is still possible to delete the line, I think this means that the line is not readonly. =(